# В каких случаях синхронность лучше асинхронности и почему?

Tags: сервер, сеть, асинхронность

Асинхронные вещи с event loop по типу node.js или python tornado, как правило, используют в случае, когда нужно работать с кучей блокирующих операций - обращения к сети, загрузка файлов на сервер, сокеты и т.д. Но почему в других случаях используются синхронные решения?
К вопросу меня приводит примерно такой ход мысли:
- нам нужна асинхронность (явные случаи, описанные выше)? - пишем на чем-то асинхронном, здесь все очевидно.
- нам не нужна асинхронность? - вроде как асинхронный event loop не должен мешать в этом случае. почему не писать все на асинхронных технологиях?
Подозреваю, что у синхронных технологий есть свои преимущества перед асинхронными в случае, например, написания новостного сайта, но я их просто пока не понимаю.

Собственно, вопрос заключается в следующем: в каких случаях синхронность лучше асинхронности (конкретно event loop) и почему?

Comment: Синхронность проще, поэтому следуйте KISS-принципу (пока возможно).

Comment: @avp, дело в том, что на python (который я использую) одинаково просто писать и синхронное приложение на flask (которое потом все равно будет жить с асинхронным nginx), и асинхронное на tornado. вот я и решил понять вообще как оно там внутри и почему используют одно, а не другое

Comment: Вы немного не поняли. Синхронность всегда *логически проще* (а Вас что, код волнует?)

Comment: @avp, учитывая что вся логика спрятана от меня глубоко внутри сервера/фреймворка крутыми дядьками, то меня волнует больше... наверное, потребление ресурсов... или другие причины, по которым асинхронность используют только в случаях скопления блокирующих операций, а не всюду и всегда.

Comment: Я имел в виду, естественно, *логику конечного приложения*, а вовсе не реализацию фреймворка.

Answer (score 5):

Основная проблема с асинхронностью - это организация взаимодействия между потоками. Каждый поток в результате чего-то где-то генерирует - некий выхлоп, результат. Этот выхлоп сам по себе неинтересен, он интересен только тогда когда этот результат может быть где-то применен.

Если все пытаться делать асинхронно, то потоки должны постоянно общаться друг с другом, и тут начинается... потоки идут неравномерно один вперед убежал, второй запоздал, третий вообще набок завалился. Синхронизация всей этой истории та еще задача - это ночной кошмар программиста.

Поэтому асинхронность имеет смысл для задач когда потоки взаимодействуют друг с другом в строго изолированных местах: типа есть начало потока (начальные данные), сам поток где что-то вычисляется, далее окончание потока где от потока получаем результат. В противном случае получается каша где нужно непрерывно синхронизировать потоки, останавливать, ждать, джойнить и проч. семафорно-мьютексные истории.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы ответил так:

- Асинхронность лучше там, где подразумевается много IO(input-output)
- Синхронность лучше там, где требуется производить "тяжелые" операции

*Немного подробнее:* давайте попробуем взглянуть на банальный сервер, который читает команды клиента и что-то отвечает клиенту.

Асинхронный путь выглядит в данном случае так:

1. заводим event loop, ставящий задачи в очередь;
2. дергаем указанный callback, когда какая-то задача выполнилась;
3. обрабатываем этот event loop в один или несколько потоков.

Итак, представим себе, что callback - очень "тяжелая" функция, производит мощные расчеты и выполняется, например, секунду. Так вот, если наш event loop обрабатывается только одним потоком, и на сервер пришел один клиент, то в течение секунды наш сервер не сможет принимать входящие сообщения от других клиентов, пока event loop занят вычислением callback. Если event loop обрабатывается в 2 потока, то в таком случае два параллельно подключившихся клиента уже делают невозможным (на секунду) подключение третьего клиента. И так далее.

Эта проблема, в принципе, имеет решение. Можно "тяжелые" задачи тоже выполнять асинхронно, но для этого потребуется еще один пул потоков, специально под эти "тяжелые" задачи, и потребуется наладить взаимодействие между двумя пулами потоков. А это уже - не так-то просто и, насколько я знаю, прямо из коробки такого функционала нету в асинхронных фреймворках.
Кроме того, с числом потоков тут тоже надо не переборщить, иначе можно получить серьезную деградацию производительности.

На этом же примере видно преимущество синхронного пути. Мы, например, просто форкаем сервер для каждого нового клиента (самое простое), и в этом процессе-форке синхронно читаем команду, потом выполняем вычисления, потом отвечаем клиенту и завершаем работу. Никаких дополнительных сложностей не возникает..по крайней мере до тех пор, пока нам будет хватать памяти на сервере, чтобы держать в памяти копию сервера на каждого клиента :)

PS: Надеюсь, сущности типа callback и event loop не вызывают вопросов - это, в общем, основы асинхронного программирования, и я не расписывал подробно, что это. В некоторых фреймворках это может быть настолько глубоко спрятано, что может вызывать ложные представления о работе программы.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый асинхронный вызов - это отдельный поток, плюс какие-то дополнительные сущности (мьютектсы, семафоры...), плюс усложнение логики работы вашей программы. Даже, если, конкретный фреймворк от вас это все скрывает, внутри это все равно есть. Мое мнение, что не надо вырезать гланды через задний проход, а если возможно писать проще - пишите проще.

Comment: Ну так если "конкретный фреймворк от вас это все скрывает", то разве не получится "пишите проще"? Ведь любой язык от вас много чего скрывает, и потому вы пишите на нем, а не на asm`e

Comment: @ВОРОН Если фреймворк от вас что либо скрывает, это не значит что его нет - это значит что вы не можете на это повлиять, а ресурсы он потребляет и "свое поведение имеет". Это не значит что нам всем надо пересесть на асм, это значит что конкретную технологию нужно применять только там где она будет полезна, и держать в виду ее "побочные действия".

Comment: @Mirdin, а на сколько заметны обычно эти побочные действия? Например, это лишних n мегабайт оперативной памяти на n пользователей или просто какой-то малозаметный, но неприятный побочный эффект?

Comment: Вы писали "плюс усложнение логики работы вашей программы", я на это и ответил. Если детали будут скрыты, то в каком месте логика усложнится? Обычно наоборот все получается, я потому про asm и написал. На том же не самом быстром питоне писать намного удобнее именно потому, что детали скрыты

Comment: @fobeder, а это зависит от вашей программы, объекты с которыми вы работаете могут иметь например большой размер, или результат выполнения вот этой конкретной функции будет безполезен без какой либо другой и придется хранит что либо в памяти пока и она не выполнится.

Comment: "Каждый асинхронный вызов - это отдельный поток, плюс какие-то дополнительные сущности (мьютектсы, семафоры...)" -- чересчур громкое заявление. Если мы говорим об асинхронном IO, то никаких потоков и сущностей нет (http://habrahabr.ru/post/216659/). По крайней мере на уровне приложения.

Comment: @ВОРОН, я ведь не говорю используйте асм, я говорю используйте подходящий инструмент в подходящем месте и помните об его недостатках. А об усложнении логики - логика "черного ящика" сложна абсолютно

Comment: @fobeder, статья там вообще не о том, автор пишет (ну как я понял) о потоках уровня ОС, а их действительно может и не быть, но в вашей программе будут свои потоки команд, данных, которыми вам и придется "жонглировать".

Answer (score 1):

Синхронность лучше асинхронности в тех случаях, когда используемые инструменты плохо поддерживают асинхронность.

Хорошая поддержка асинхронности - это когда
 1. код не похож на лапшу,
 2. при появлении исключительной ситуации стек вызовов не теряется,
 3. отладчик не спотыкается на асинхронных вызовах,
 4. используемые библиотеки не против асинхронного кода.

Если все условия выполняются - нет никаких причин использовать синхронные вызовы, даже если задача позволяет. Если что-то не так - то синхронный код всегда будет проще асинхронного.

Answer (score 1):

Ситуации, в которых следует использовать синхронное/асинхронное взаимодействие, перечислить почти невозможно. Проблема состоит в том, что всегда хочется описать некоторую ситуацию в форме паттерна, чтобы охватить как можно больше конкретных случаев. Однако синхронное/асинхронное взаимодействие - это тоже паттерны, только более высокого уровня. Так что задача в итоге сводится к работе с паттернами паттернов. Это очень сложно. Не невозможно. Но это требует выдающихся интеллектуальных способностей. Любое уточнение или изменение в паттерне низшего уровня, кажущееся незначительным, может привести к тому, что данный паттерн перестанет вписываться в тот паттерн более высокого уровня, в который он вписывался ранее, и начнёт лучше соответствовать другому. Учесть в низших паттернах все нюансы практически невозможно. А уж запомнить их - тем более.

Поэтому для ответа на заданный вопрос я использую следующий мысленный хак. Нужно представить себе, что всю полезную работу на другом конце от пользователя выполняет не компьютер, а человек... или несколько людей, не взаимодействующих друг с другом напрямую, а только через контекст взаимодействия с пользователем. И затем нужно мысленно поставить вопрос: как в данных конкретных обстоятельствах лучше организовать взаимодействие с пользователем - по телефону (синхронно) или по электронной почте (асинхронно)? Этот хак ещё никогда не давал осечек. С его помощью всегда удаётся выбрать правильную модель с первого раза. И чем дольше я им пользуюсь, тем сильнее начинаю подозревать, что это не хак. Видимо, взаимодействие между людьми имеет гораздо больше общего с взаимодействием между подпрограммами, чем это может показаться.

Answer (score -1):

Например, аутентификация и/или авторизация. Когда мы в принципе не можем дальше ничего делать, пока не получим ответ.

Кроме того:

Вспомним асинхронное взаимодействие в распределённых системах. Оно реализуется с помощью передачи сообщений. И при этом у нас есть три принципиальных вида гарантий доставки:

- Доставить минимум один раз
- Доставить максимум один раз
- Доставить ровно один раз.

И если первые два варианта - это как раз то, для чего асинхронное взаимодействие замечательно подходит, то третий вариант связан с большими накладными расходами и граблями.

Поэтому в том случае, когда передача сообщения должна осуществиться ровно один раз, как правило лучше использовать синхронное взаимодействие.

То же самое применимо и к локально выполняющимся задачам.

В голову приходят примеры, скажем, из банковской сферы. Допустим, положить на счёт пять долларов. Или, более общо, неидемпотентные транзакции. То есть такие, которые при выполнении создают накапливающиеся побочные эффекты. Или отличающиеся друг от друга побочные эффекты.